# Android ssl session ticket support

Tags: android, ssl, reusability

A server support rfc5077,so support ssl session ticket and session ticket reuse,i also test the server use c/c++ client.

and the android client i use

m = mSSLSocket.getClass().getMethod("setUseSessionTickets", boolean.class);
           m.invoke(mSSLSocket, true);

so the client can get the session ticket from the server side,but can not reuse the session  ticket,i use the code snippet like this:

```
 SSLSessionCache cache = new SSLSessionCache(mContext);
 socketFactory = SSLCertificateSocketFactory.getInsecure(30000000, cache);
```

why it does not work?

thanks in advance for any suggestion.